# JavaScript for loop not working with VS Code extension API

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I'm writing a VS Code extension in JavaScript. It requires a loop to open several text files so I used a `for` loop. Here's my a sample of the code for the loop:

```
const allFiles = vscode.workspace.findFiles('**/*.*', '**/node_modules/**');

    for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) { 
        vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(allFiles[i])
    }
```

Here's the whole `extension.js` file:

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
const vscode = require('vscode');
const path = require('path')

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "code-runner-from-the-web" is now active!');
    const allFiles = vscode.workspace.findFiles('**/*.*', '**/node_modules/**');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with  registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('code-runner-from-the-web.helloWorld', function () {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed

        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from Code Runner From The Web!');
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.legnth; i++) { 
        console.log (vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(allFiles[i]))
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('code-runner.run', null)
    }
        

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use an `async` function.

```
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
const vscode = require('vscode');
const path = require('path')

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
async function activate(context) {

    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "code-runner-from-the-web" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with  registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('code-runner-from-the-web.helloWorld', function () {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed

        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from Code Runner From The Web!');

        const getAllFiles = vscode.workspace.findFiles('**/*.*', '**/node_modules/**');

        const findFile = async () => {
            const allFiles = await getAllFiles
            console.log(allFiles)
            for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(allFiles[i])
                //vscode.commands.executeCommand('code-runner.run', null)
                console.log("Hello!!!!")
            }
        }
        findFile()

    });
    
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() { }

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the for loop. Instead of allFiles.legnth, it should be allFiles.length. The corrected code should be:

```
for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) { 
    console.log (vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(allFiles[i]))
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('code-runner.run', null)
}
```

Comment: Use that was one of two problems. The other problem was I was trying to get the length of a promise. Instead, I needed to use the ```async``/```await``` syntax to convert the promise to an array.